# Displaying multiple summeries in R code

Tags: r

I am new to Stack overflow, and also to R programming so please forgive if the question is a bit silly sounding.

What I would like to ask anyone in the know is if it is possible to display multiple summaries from just one code command.

Just to give an example of what I am trying to achieve: The data frame consists of daily climate data over a number of years (includes around 6 various variables)

```
sub <- subset(data, Month == "Sep" & Day==2, !is.na(data), select = MSLP:Temp)
summary(sub,mean)

      MSLP        Direction         Speed             Temp      
 Min.   : 976   Min.   :  8.4   Min.   : 1.680   Min.   : 8.18  
 1st Qu.:1007   1st Qu.:167.8   1st Qu.: 6.095   1st Qu.:13.04  
 Median :1016   Median :229.7   Median :10.010   Median :14.73  
 Mean   :1014   Mean   :213.0   Mean   :10.042   Mean   :14.68  
 3rd Qu.:1022   3rd Qu.:270.4   3rd Qu.:13.320   3rd Qu.:16.40  
 Max.   :1034   Max.   :353.6   Max.   :25.640   Max.   :21.58
```

All good so far. But what I would like to ask, if anybody would know,  is if it would be possible to include something in the above code to display a summary for each day over a set period? Say from day 2 through to day 10.

Also if OK, would it be possible to include another critera in the above code to include a specific year? IE:

```
sub <- subset(data, Month == "Sep" & Day==2 - include year etc.
```

as I just cannot figure it out at all. For eg, if I do

```
sub <- subset(data, Month == "Sep" & Day==2 & Year == 1967 #etc ...)
```

I just get an error code like this:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos)
```

Apologies again if these questions seem a little idiotic but if anybody has any solutions to the above I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please include sample input data and be clear on what you want the desired output to be. You should always try to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when asking questions. But it sounds like the `aggregate` function might be a better choice. Or pe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you certainly can!  If you're printing the results to the console with the `summary` function, I'm assuming there's not going to be too many days (<100 or so) you want summaries for.  In which case a simple for loop, might be all you need.

Heres an example with the `mtcars` dataset (comes with R) 
    data(mtcars)
    summary(mtcars)

```
for(i in unique(mtcars$cyl)) {
  print(paste("summary for dataset when cyl ==", i))
  print(summary(mtcars[mtcars$cyl==i,]))
}
```

In your case, I think you could use this to print a summary for days 2-10:

```
for(i in 2:10) {
  print(paste("summary for day ==", i))
  sub <- subset(data, Month == "Sep" & Day==i, !is.na(data), select = MSLP:Temp)
  print(summary(sub)
}
```

You can definitely include a third condition such as `Year==1967` in your subset function.  Perhaps Year is not defined?  The `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos)` usually arises when an object is not defined.  try `class(data$Year)` to make sure `data$Year` is of type numeric or integer.

Comment: ajb, thank you so much for your response and helpful reply! I tested the mtcars example and works a treat! as does the function for my own dataset which you very kindly put together! But only one problem, which is without doubt something very wrong I am doing, All the results in summary lists come up as 'NA' or 'NAN'. I have tried to mess around the the 'na.rm = TRUE' command, but no matter where I place it in the function, it will not work. EG:

  sub <- subset(data, Month == "Sep" & Date==i, na.rm=T, select =

Sorry for being a pain, but if you could please kindly advise. & ty for xtra tips

Comment: can you copy the output of what R spits out when you run `str(data)`

Comment: Upon further inspection... if you want to just select the columns named "MSLP" and "Temp", you want:
`subset(data, Month == "Sep" & Day==2, select = c("MSLP", "Temp"))`

If you want to remove NAs from this dataframe, see this [post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342435/efficient-method-to-subset-drop-rows-with-na-values-in-r)

There might be a cleaner way, but 2 steps will work:

`df1 <- subset(data, Month == "Sep" & Day==2, select = c("MSLP", "Temp"))`

`df2 <- [rowSums(is.na(df1))==0, ]`

Comment: Hi ajb, thanks again for response!
str(data)
'data.frame': 2168 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Year     : int  2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 ...
 $ Month    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Date     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Day      : int  5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
 $ Full.Date: Factor w/ 2066 levels "","2009-01-01",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 $ Max      : num  3.3 3.2 2.4 6.6 4.9 1.5 2.4 3.7 6.6 9.1 ...
 $ Min      : num  1.7 -0.7 -3 1.2 -3 -5.8 -5.7 -1.4 0.6 2.8 ...
 $ Rain     : num  0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 12.8 ...
 $ Wind     : num  17.4 13.1 7.8 7.5 11.1 6 6.6

Comment: Just to add, I am using a different, smaller dataset to practice on, with slightly different headers. And as you can see, its a bit of a mess. Please accept my apologies for all these questions. I attempted the '2 steps', but getting error 'Error: unexpected '[' in "df2 <- (["'

R is a fantastic program, but very very frustrating at times.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it to work (minus the NAs/NANS) by tweeking ajb's very helpful function a little.

The following function displays individual summaries for selected variables in each of the 31 days in August:

```
for(i in 1:31) {
print(paste("summary for date ==", i))
x <- subset(df, Month == 8 & Date==i, select = V1:V4)
print(summary(x,is.na=T[x$Date==i,]))
}
```

Still produces error messages so obviously it needs to be tweeked more but main thing is the results are still produced.

Edit, found the problem. A useless 'is.na' function placed within the 'x' function produced error messages despite producing desired result. Above function has been edited and produces a cleaner result.